# How do I pass a function as a parameter in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: variables, emacs

I'm trying to add a function I created to a hook, but the obvious (to my Schemer mind) way doesn't seem to work. The function is used in 2 places and I want to keep my code DRY so no anonymous function. Though I could wrap my function in a lambda, there must be a better way.

Doesn't work:

```
(defun my-function ()
   ;; do my stuff)

(add-hook 'some-hook-list my-function)
```

I get the error message:

> Symbol's value as variable is void:
>   my-function

Comment: Emacs Lisp is a lisp-2, not a lisp-1 like Scheme.  Functions are in their own namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. It's pretty simple. Just quote the function:

Fixed code:
    (defun my-function ()
       ;; do my stuff)

```
(add-hook 'some-hook-list 'my-function) ;;; There's a quote before my-function
```

Comment: To be clear 'foo is shorthand for (function foo) (which is the same as (quote foo) in elisp, but not in other lisp-2s like CL).